# Matplotlib find negative peaks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I already have a code for finding peaks in `.trc` files. But now I want the same for a Frequency analyzer, so all the Values are negative. See picture of the values below. I basically only want the peaks, that are marked in this picture shown.

[image: ![values]

The problem is, that now my code finds no peaks at all. Is it possible to find and mark those peaks?

Here is the code I am using:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from readTrc import Trc
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import math

from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(8, 6))
trc=Trc()
fName = "SpecAn--SIMMP-458366--00000.trc"
datX, datY,d = trc.open(fName)
x = datX
y = datY

ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_ylim(-120, 20)
ax1.set_title('Press left mouse button and drag '
              'to select a region in the top graph')

line2, = ax2.plot([], [])


def onselect(xmin, xmax):
    indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(x, (xmin, xmax))
    indmax = min(len(x) - 1, indmax)

    region_x = x[indmin:indmax]
    region_y = y[indmin:indmax]


    if len(region_x) >= 2:
        line2.set_data(region_x, region_y)
        ax2.set_xlim(region_x[0], region_x[-1])
        ax2.set_ylim(region_y.min(), region_y.max())
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        
        thresh_top    = np.median(x) + 1 * np.std(x)
        peak,d   = find_peaks(region_y,  height =  thresh_top)
        peaks= list(d.values())[0]
        print(peaks)

span = SpanSelector(
    ax1,
    onselect,
    "horizontal",
    useblit=True,
    props=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor="tab:blue"),
    interactive=True,
    drag_from_anywhere=True
)
# Set useblit=True on most backends for enhanced performance.

plt.show()
```

I expect an array with at least 3 peaks, which show me the most common frequencies in my sweep.
The only problem are the negative values I think.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The negative values should not be a problem per se. However, most likely 'thresh_top' is too large compared to your peaks. Without having access to your data we can only guess, though. Try to leave height empty in find_peaks or set it manually to something like -40 and run it again. This should give you some results.

Comment: Thanks, now I find some peaks, but only the ones around 40MHz and some in the middle. Is it possibly to define a span until the next peak (for example between peak1 and peak2 have to be at least 1MHz difference in the x-values)?

Comment: Yes you can. Use the keyword argument 'distance' for that: 'find_peaks(region_y, distance=1000000)'. I would suggest to have a detailed look at the documentation of 'find_peaks' as there are a lot more options to filter for peaks with specific features.

Answer (score 0):

You set the `height` argument to a value related to x-range, not to y-range. If I change that to y-range of the selected region, it works. The example below is based on your code with some random data:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import math

from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(8, 6))
# fake data
x = np.linspace(0, 50000000, 1000)
y = -120 * np.random.rand(1000)

ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_ylim(-120, 20)
ax1.set_title('Press left mouse button and drag '
              'to select a region in the top graph')

line2, = ax2.plot([], [])


def onselect(xmin, xmax):
    indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(x, (xmin, xmax))
    indmax = min(len(x) - 1, indmax)

    region_x = x[indmin:indmax]
    region_y = y[indmin:indmax]


    if len(region_x) >= 2:
        line2.set_data(region_x, region_y)
        ax2.set_xlim(region_x[0], region_x[-1])
        tenth_of_y_range = (region_y.max() - region_y.min())/10  # expand the y-range a little, to see markers around peaks
        ax2.set_ylim(region_y.min() - tenth_of_y_range, region_y.max() + tenth_of_y_range)
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        
        thresh_top = np.median(region_y) + 1 * np.std(region_y)
        print(thresh_top)
        peak,d   = find_peaks(region_y, height=thresh_top)
        heights = d['peak_heights']  # list of the heights of the peaks
        peak_pos = region_x[peak]  # list of the peaks positions
        ax2.scatter(peak_pos, heights, color='red', s=80, marker='d')
        print(peak)
        print(peak_pos)
        print(heights)

span = SpanSelector(
    ax1,
    onselect,
    "horizontal",
    useblit=True,
    props=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor="tab:blue"),
    interactive=True,
    drag_from_anywhere=True
)

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

The printed values of `thresh_top`, `peak`, `peak_pos`, and `heights`:

```
-53.98393411327325
[ 7 10]
[350350.35035035 500500.5005005 ]
[-18.94600211 -30.92933164]
```